# How to generate aware time object in Faker?

Tags: python, django, class, faker, factory-boy

I have the following (simplified) model and factory:

models.py

```
class Event():
    duration = FloatField()
    start_time = TimeField()
    finish_time = DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.finish_time = self.start_time + timedelta(hours=self.duration)
```

event_factory.py

```
from factory import Faker

class EventFactory:
    date = Faker(
        "date_time_this_month",
        before_now=False,
        after_now=True,
        tzinfo=timezone.get_current_timezone(),
        )
    start_time = Faker("time_object")
    duration = Faker("random_int")
```

However, my `save` method raises `Warning: DateTimeField Event.finish_time received a naive datetime (2022-03-28 12:43:38) while time zone support is active.`

`date` is aware due to `tzinfo` argument, but `start_time` is naive (I checked with django's `timezone.is_aware()`), because time providers in Faker do not seem to allow any timezone parameters.

Any suggestion in getting a fake aware time object in factory-boy/Faker?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use FuzzyDateTime objects, they return a timezone aware object: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fuzzy.html?highlight=timezone

Comment: Thank you. I ended up just hard-coding my dates and times with the `datetime` module. I'll give FuzzyDateTime a try, however the note in the docs baffles me:

`Now that FactoryBoy includes the factory.Faker class, most of these built-in fuzzers are deprecated in favor of their Faker equivalents.`